# how to run nodemailer on MongoDB Realm? nodemailer failed to execute on MongoDB Realm

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nodemailer, mongodb-realm

how to run nodemailer on MongoDB Realm?
nodemailer failed to execute on MongoDB Realm

code:

```
    const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

exports = async function (changeEvent) {
  try {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "somthing@gmail.com",
        pass: "passw0rd",
      },
    });

    let info = transporter.sendMail({
      from: "something@gmail.com",
      to: "wdcjdwzcvpbagtd@frederictonlawyer.com",
      subject: "YesterDay Report Details!",
      html: `
<div style=" text-align: center;" >
    style=" width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-top: 10px;" />
    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
    <p>
    <span style=" color: rgb(99, 99, 99); font-weight: bold;">
    adminMail </span>, hi there!
     </p>
    
    <br />    
    
    <p style="margin-top: 20px; color: gray;">
    This link expire in 10 minutes</p>
    
    <h5>Total Income Aomunt   : </h5>
    <h5>Avrage Income Aomunt  : </h5>
    <h5>Patientions Count     : </h5>
    <h5>Over-reported Disease : </h5>
    <h5>Reported All Disease  : </h5>
    
    <p>Thanks and Regards</p>
    
    <div style="margin-top: 50px;">&copy; 2021 Apollo</div>
  </div>
`,
    });

    if (info) {
      console.log(info);
    }

    console.log(
      `Successfully send daily report Mail to wdcjdwzcvpbagtd@frederictonlawyer.com :)`
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to run the function : ", err);
  }
};
```

output:

[image]

> ran at Thu Jan 13 2022 17:33:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
> error:
> failed to execute source for 'node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js': TypeError: 'networkInterfaces' is not a function
> at node_modules/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js:41:80(63)

```
at require (native)
at node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:37:22(39)

at require (native)
at node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:13:22(13)
```

> ran at Thu Jan 13 2022 17:33:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
> error:
> failed to execute source for 'node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js': TypeError: 'networkInterfaces' is not a function
> at node_modules/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js:41:80(63)

```
at require (native)
at node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:37:22(39)

at require (native)
at node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:13:22(13)
```

but it's work on my system...

[image]

[image]

Comment: can u see the dependencies on the web UI

Comment: just nodemailer

Comment: nodemailer@6.4.10 is support on MonogoDB Realm.                                                
some old version node mailer is working on mongoDB Realm...                                                                      **Dev Post Link** : https://dev.to/jacksonkasi/hospital-management-system-using-mongodb-with-nodejs-and-ejs-5gek

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `nodemailer` as a dependency

In the `Functions` screen, you will see a  `dependencies` tab. Click on it and follow the instructions to add `nodemailer` as a dependency.

[image: Functions Screen]

Comment: sir, I am already add dependencies  "nodemailer" . but still same error